# PDFBox won't read properly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to read PDF-documents with PDFBox, but I've run into 2 problems:

1) The documents are sometimes not read at all. Some of my documents are from 2005, does this affect the reading capabilities? If so, are there any solutions for this?

2) I'm getting the warnings below when I run my code, why?

Warnings:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

My method:

```
public String readPDF(String companyNumber){

    File file = new File("/users/josh/Documents/2017-8495/"+companyNumber);

          String docText = null;

          try {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            docText = stripper.getText(PDDocument.load(file));

          }catch (Exception e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          return docText;

}
```

Comment: 1. No, it only depends on how the PDFs are created. Not *all* text from *all* PDFs can *always* be extracted correctly. That being possible is not a mandatory part of the PDF specifications.

Comment: @Jongware Do you know of some library that can extract text from images, then?

Comment: Company line: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. (But you should search for an OCR library: "Optical Character Recognition".) Since it's also Stack Overflow policy to have 1 question per *question*, you may want to remove your #1 from your post. The other q. does seem on topic to me.

Comment: You should close a document after reading it. Hint: `PDDocument` implements `AutoCloseable`, so you can use a try-with-resources. Also *"The documents are sometimes not read at all"* isn't a good desctiption. What are the differences between documents that are read correctly and the ones that aren't? What exactly happens? What is the result? Is there a exception? The date of creation shouldn't be important.

Comment: @fabian What I mean is that some documents don't return any text at all, there are no exceptions. The result is nothing.

Comment: @martin re q2, did you read the message? It says "See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info." re q1: see https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#notext